# How to display title of attached image in post?

Tags: images

First of all, I apologize for my English, because my English isn't good.

How to display **[title of attached image](http://prntscr.com/5oqna8)** between < h3 > tags in the post?

---

There's that code in wp-includes/media.php file;

```
    return '<h3>' . $atts['title'] . '</h3><div ' . $atts['id'] . $style . 'class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">'
. do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $atts['caption'] . '</p></div>';
```

...

```
$atts['caption']
```

is calling image caption correctly. But;

```
$atts['title']
```

is doesn't call image title.

I try this;

```
$title = get_the_title( $attachment_id );
```

and i insert $title variable into following code;

```
return '<h3>' . $title . '</h3><div ' . $atts['id'] . $style . 'class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">'
. do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $atts['caption'] . '</p></div>';
```

But this way don't work. What can i do?

Comment: How are you setting the image, in the backend of WordPress and how are you currently displaying it in your template? Are you asking how to add the image title to all images inserted into othe post?

Comment: When i insert image into post and save it, my post look like this: http://prntscr.com/5owuez

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get your attached image ID, how you get it depends on how you're setting the image. The generic idea is that you get the attachment ID then you can simply use `get_the_title( $attachment_id )`.

If you're setting it as a Featured Image ( Post Thumbnail ) then you can use the following function to get the image ID: [`get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id).